# Xamarin Android - Call C# with JavaScript

Tags: android, xamarin

Using Xamarin Android: I am trying to call C# code from JavaScript in a WebView as set out in the example - http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/webview/call_csharp_from_javascript/ . However, the code complains on "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method run()". Please advise how this can be fixed.

Comment: I believe "run" is a typo - try "Run" instead.

Comment: I have tried Run() in vain. The document explains towards the bottom on why javascript needs to call run() instead of Run().